# Loading properties.yaml files from file system in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am facing troubles loading yaml files from the file system with spring boot.

I have placed my properties.yaml files in a folder

```
\config\source.properties
\config\config.yml
```

and I am calling the jar with the command

```
java -jar myjar.jar --spring.config.location=\config
```

I'm loading the properties file like this and it works fine.

```
@PropertySource("${spring.config.location}/source.properties")
```

But the below snippet does not load the yaml properties

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test-data")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@Data
public class TestData {

    private Map<String, MyObject1> object1Map = new HashMap<>();

    private Map<Integer, MyObject2> object2Map= new HashMap<>();
}
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: You must pass the location as follows while running the jar `-Dspring.config.location=/config`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try giving a '/' at the end of location parameter as mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

the parameter you mentioned: `--spring.config.location=\config` will look for properties file at this location, and it must end with'/' or you can specify complete path including the file name. or By Default, it will look for application.yml or application.properties.

In your case, it must be trying to find the file 'config'

In order to use a different name for properties, you need to specify that using name. Refer this '[boot-features-external-config'](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)